# std::atomic<int> decrement and comparison

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++11, atomic

On the following code:

```cpp
std::atomic<int> myint; //Shared variable
//(...)
if( --myint == 0) {
    //Code block B
}
```

Is it possible that more than one thread access the block I named "Code Block B"?

Please consider that overflow will not happen, that the 'if' is being executed concurrently by more than one thread, that the only modification to *myint* in the whole program is the *--myint* inside the if and that *myint* is initialized with a positive value.

Comment: Why do you think it should not be possible? If that is the only operation you do on `myint` it will eventually overflow.

Comment: @Patrick that would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: The real question is if std::atomic<int>::operator-- atomically returns the old value.

Comment: @cdleonard - The decrement is atomic and the result is returned. However, nothing prevents another thread from immediately increment or decrement the value again while you compare the result to zero.

Comment: @BoPersson But the value that is returned will not be modified by any subsequent modifications to myint.  So, theoretically, if the value of myint is monotonically decreasing (discounting overflow), then only a single thread *could* enter the block.

Comment: "_Please consider that overflow/underflow will not happen_" <mode=nitpicking>an integer never underflows. It can only overflow!</mode>

Comment: @curiousguy I dont know what you are talking about, I never said "underflow" on my  question... =)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

C++0x paper [N2427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html#atomics.operations) (atomics) states roughly the following.  I've changed the wording slightly so its easier to read for the specific decrement situation, the parts I changed are in **bold**:

> Effects:
>   Atomically replace the *value* in *object* with result of the **decrement** applied to the *value* in *object* and the given operand. Memory is affected as per order. These operations are read-modify-write operations in the sense of the "synchronizes with" definition in [the new section added by N2334 or successor], and hence both such an operation and the evaluation that produced the input value synchronize with any evaluation that reads the updated value.
>
> Returns:
>      Atomically, the value of *object* immediately before the **decrement**.

The atomic operation guarantees that the decrement operator will return the value that the variable held immediately before the operation, this is atomic so there can be no intermediate value from updates by another thread.

This means the following are *the only* possible executions of this code with 2 threads:

```
(Initial Value: 1)
Thread 1: Decrement 
Thread 1: Compare, value is 0, enter region of interest
Thread 2: Decrement
Thread 2: Compare, value is -1, don't enter region
```

or

```
(Initial Value: 1)
Thread 1: Decrement 
Thread 2: Decrement
Thread 1: Compare, value is 0, enter region of interest
Thread 2: Compare, value is -1, don't enter region
```

Case 1 is the uninteresting expected case.

Case 2 interleaves the decrement operations and executes the comparison operations later.  Because the decrement-and-fetch operation is *atomic*, it is impossible for thread 1 to receive a value other than 0 for comparison.  It *cannot* receive a -1 because the operation was atomic... the read takes place at the time of the decrement and *not* at the time of the comparison.   More threads will not change this behavior.

Comment: Note that I checked N3291, and though it uses different wording, it agrees with this.

Comment: Is this still correct for " --myint; if(myint == 0) { }" ?

Comment: @paulm It is absolutely not true if you decrement and check in two different statements.  Has to be done in the same statement.

Answer (score 3):

It is not obvious that the code block will always execute. If the operator "--" is implemented in such a way that it stores the old value in its returning value and decrements in a single atomic instruction (I'm pretty sure x86 has such instructions), then yes, it should act like a mutual exclusion block for multiple threads. I'm not sure how it works by default, but the answer lies probably in the new standard documentation:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html

Answer (score -2):

No it is not possible that more than one thread enters the block, given your constraints. But neither is it guaranteed that any thread ever enters this block:

```
thread A: decrement myint to 0

thread B: decrement myint to -1

thread A: compare to 0 -> false -> don't enter (and neither anyone else)
```

If this is a problem (which I assume), then this code won't work (at least not **always**).

Comment: so what if I have: thread A: decrement to 1, thread B: decrement to 0, thread A: compare to 0 true, thread B: compare to 0 true.

Comment: @AndréPuel Ah, I think you got me (and your answer).

Comment: @AndréPuel That's not possible, the -- operator does a decrement and fetch in a single instruction, so even in the execution order you specified in your comment the value in thread A would be 1.

Comment: @SoapBox Thats exactly what I am asking! Does operator-- standard defines that the decrement and fetch must be done atomically?